# SQL Server: table join based on record-dependent values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

There's a general type of query I'm trying to perform, and I'm not sure how to express it in words so that I can find a discussion of best practices and examples for executing it.

Here's an example use case.

I have a `customers` table that has info about customers and an `orders` table.  I want to fetch a subset of records from `orders` based on customer characteristics, limited by the "earliest" and "latest" dates contained as data in the `customers` table.  It's essential to the solution that I limit my query results to within this date range, which varies by customer.

**CUSTOMERS**

```
+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
| CustomerID |  Location  | Industry | EarliestActiveOrder | LatestActiveOrder |
+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
|        001 | New York   | Finance  | 2017-11-03          | 2019-07-30        |
|        002 | California | Tech     | 2018-06-18          | 2019-09-22        |
|        003 | New York   | Finance  | 2015-09-30          | 2019-02-26        |
|        004 | California | Finance  | 2019-02-02          | 2019-08-15        |
|        005 | New York   | Finance  | 2017-10-19          | 2018-12-20        |
+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

**ORDERS**

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | StartDate  | Details |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+
|     5430 |        003 | 2015-06-30 |     ... |
|     5431 |        003 | 2016-03-31 |     ... |
|     5432 |        003 | 2018-09-30 |     ... |
|     5434 |        001 | 2018-11-05 |     ... |
|     5435 |        001 | 2019-10-11 |     ... |
```

A sample use case expressed in words would be: "Give me all Active Orders from Finance customers in New York".

Desired result is to return the full records from `orders` table for `OrderID`'s `5431,5432,5434`.

What is a generally good approach for structuring this kind of query, given an `orders` table with ~10^6 records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a join:

```
select o.*
from orders o
inner join customers c 
    on  c.Customer_id = o.Customer_id
    and o.StartDate between c.EarliestActiveOrder  and c.LatestActiveOrder
    and c.Industry = 'Finance'
    and c.Location = 'New York'
```

For performance in this query, consider the following indexes:

```
orders(customer_id,  StartDate)
customers(Customer_id, Industry, Location, EarliestActiveOrder, LatestActiveOrder)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the result set is a small subset of the orders (say less then 1% of orders but the 1% is for illustration), I would phrase the query like this:

```
select o.*
from customers c join
     orders o
     on o.Customer_id = c.Customer_id and
        o.StartDate between c.EarliestActiveOrder  and c.LatestActiveOrder
where c.Location = 'New York' and c.industry = 'Finance';
```

The indexing strategy is tricky.  For smallish result sets, you probably want to restrict the customers first and then find the matching orders.  This approach suggsts indexes on:

- `customers(location, industry, customer_id, EarliestActiveOrder, LatestActiveOrder)`
- `orders(customer_id, startdate)`

If you had other columns for filtering, you would need separate indexes for them.  For instance, for `industry`-only filtering:

- `customers(industry, customer_id, EarliestActiveOrder, LatestActiveOrder)`

This can get cumbersome.

If, on the other hand, your result set is likely to be a significant number of orders, then scanning the `orders` table might be more efficient.  You can try to rely on the optimizer.  Or just push it in the right direction by phrasing the query as:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (select 1
              from customers c
              where o.Customer_id = c.Customer_id and
                    o.StartDate between c.EarliestActiveOrder  and c.LatestActiveOrder and
                    c.Location = 'New York' and c.industry = 'Finance'
             );
```

In this case, you want an index on `customers(customer_id)` -- but that is probably already the primary key so you are fine.  This has the advantage that you don't need to worry about the exact filtering criteria.  The downside is a full table scan on `orders` (but not additional work for a `join`, `group by`, or `order by`).